# How to extract a cell in google sheets if multiple other cells on same row meets criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I have collected a lot of data into a google sheet through google forms. I would like to extract specific parts of this data on to a presentable page of the sheet. For example, I would like to extract the name of an individual who's response correlates with 5 other bits of data (a specific shift, station worked on etc).

I tried using the filter function, however this function extracts the whole row, whereas I want a specific cell.

I also tried using Vlookup function but that can only compare one bit of data, whereas I need many criteria to match for the correct cell to be extracted.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can filter a specific column depending on values in other columns. For example `=FILTER(A:A,B:B="this",C:C>100,D:D<>"that")` would return the value in column A when the other three conditions are met. Try it and update the question if you need specific help on the application of this

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know FILTERs worked like that, I thought you had to put in the entire range to be considered first. Thanks, this worked perfectly @Martín

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the AppScript. I think it will be something like

```
function myFunction(){
    //TO LOAD THE DATA
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheeApp.getActive();
    let sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('THE_NAME_OF_SHEET_HERE');
    let data = sheet.getSheetValues(1,1,-1,-1);
    let arr_response=[];
    
    //THE FOREACH ON DATA (BELOW) REPRESENT EACH ROW;
    //AND THE elem[0], elem[1], ..., elem[n] REPRESENT THE COLUMNS //'A','B','C'...
    data.forEach(elem=>{
    if(elem[0]==='SOME CRITERIA'){ 
    //FOR EXAMPLE I WANT JUST THE COLUM A, COLUM C, AND COLUM F
    arr_response.push([elem[0],elem[2],elem[5]);
    })
    return arr_response

}
```

Comment: Thinking a little more, you can use a QUERY (build in function) for that. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).